# Docker File for Building Docker Image for Multi Module Java Maven Project

Tags: java, docker, maven

We have a Multi Module Project which is currently Builds in a specific order and creates a JAR and then finally ARM gets built which has all the other project as pom dependency and builds a WAR.
[Screenshot of all the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W8DZ.png)
[Order in Which Build is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbym8.png)

Now we are moving to docker and I am new in that and want something similar building but finally it should build a Docker image instead of WAR. So wanted to ask what will be the correct way, whether to keep the docker file in all the project or only in the ARM is enough which should convert war to docker image.

Can anyone provide some basic steps for writing docker file and guide to start and the correct way of implementation ?

Comment: Build like you do now, and have a final step that takes the artifact to deploy from your artifact repository and packages it in a docker image.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can you explain a little how to write the docker file for doing the above. Means downloading the WAR from the repository and packaging it to form a docker image.